# UITableView scrolling but not as expected?

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I have a tableview and there are loads of element in it, when i scroll down, it does not stay where i left the scroll, it again goes to top.

How to solve it?

```
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,66 ,320.0, 768.0);
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self addSubview:tableView];
```

my row height is 110

Comment: I think your tableview is bigger than it actually visible.
Please share some code.

Comment: see I told you your table view height is more that visible area.
please check my answer.

Comment: Hey does it worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `table` size is more than the visible area for `table`.

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,66 ,320.0, 768.0); // here is the problem
```

change change height of your table view up to visible area(say if your table is in whole screen for iPhone 5)

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,66 ,320.0, 548.0) // set according your need.
```